# How can I ensure that Dropbox is using only its folder?

Tags: file-system, storage, file-access

I'm using several cloude storage services, like Dropbox. Each have windows app for its synchronization, and this app actually can read anything from my disc, not just files from its 'synchronized' folder. I want to make sure that this apps never access any other folder except sync folder. Is there a way to do so (using VM is not an option - too much resources required).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Create a new user.
2. Give that user access rights to only the folders you want to share. You can use the [File and Folder Permission](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb727008.aspx) options on Windows, and simple [`chmod`](http://ss64.com/bash/chmod.html) on Linux.
3. Run your application (Dropbox, for example) under that user. You can use [`runas`](http://ss64.com/nt/runas.html) on Windows, and [`sudo -u`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/294736/run-a-shell-script-as-another-user-that-has-no-password) on Linux.

Please note that you might have to allow access to other folders where Dropbox keeps its cache files and configurations.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a user-mode sandbox such as [Sandboxie](http://www.sandboxie.com/).  Sandboxie intercepts API calls and only allows an application access to specific resources you define.

NOTE: I'm not sure how dropbox is implemented.  If it runs as a service it may not work.  It's still worth a try though.